# FirebaseUi phone auth Android an unknown error occured

Tags: android, firebase, android-4.4-kitkat, firebaseui

Need some help here. I implemented FirebaseUi phone authentication on Android and the last time when I tested on Android Marshmallow, the phone verification worked just fine but today, when I test it on Kitkat, it gives the error, "**An unknown error occurred**". Is there an issue with phone auth on Kitkat? How do I get around the error?

Comment: No I've tested phone auth... Have you checked the Firebase console to check Phone auth is enabled.

Comment: I have enabled phone auth in firebase console

Comment: Is it error shows after the number enter or before?

Comment: After the number is entered.

Comment: just try updating the dependencies..

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I did not add the phone-number I was testing with in Firebase console. After adding it, you should be able to get it to work.

Firebase console screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio

Open your Project

Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)

Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar, you will see List Gradle
scripts of your Project)

Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List (root))

Click on Tasks

Click on Android

Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar(Sometimes it
will be in Gradle Console))

Select app module from module selection dropdown to run or debug your application

this helped me :)